# how to convert json returned varbinary array to image and set it to imageview in android

Tags: android, arrays, json, image

web service returns varbinary array like

```
[255,216,255,224,0,16,74,70,73,70,0,1,1,1,0,96,0,96,0,0,255,219,0,67,0,8,6,6,7,6,5,8,7,7,7,9,9,8,10,12,20,13,12,11,11,12,25,18,19,15,20,29,26,31,30,29,26,28,28,32,36,46,39,32,34,44,35,28,28,40,55,41,44,48,49,52,52,52,31,39,57,61,56,50,60,46,51,52,50,255,219,0,67,1,9,9,9,12,11,12,24,13,13,24,50,33,28,33,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,255,192,0,17,8,0,100,0,100,3,1,34,0,2,17,1,3,17,1,255,196,0,31,0,0,1,5,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,255,196,0,181,16,0,2,1,3,3,2,4,3,5,5,4,4,0,0,1,125,1,2,3,0,4,17,5,18,33,49,65,6,19,81,97,7,34,113,20,50,129,145,161,8,35,66,177,193,21,82,209,240,36,51,98,114,130,9,10,22,23,24,25,26,37,38,39,40,41,42,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,99,100,101,102,103,104,105,106,115,116,117,118,119,120,121,122,131,132,133,134,135,136,137,138,146,147,148,149,150,151,152,153,154,162,163,164,165,166,167,168,169,170,178,179,180,181,182,183,184,185,186,194,195,196,197,198,199,200,201,202,210,211,212,213,214,215,216,217,218,225,226,227,228,229,230,231,232,233,234,241,242,243,244,245,246,247,248,249,250,255,196,0,31,1,0,3,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,255,196,0,181,17,0,2,1,2,4,4,3,4,7,5,4,4,0,1,2,119,0,1,2,3,17,4,5,33,49,6,18,65,81,7,97,113,19,34,50,129,8,20,66,145,161,177,193,9,35,51,82,240,21,98,114,209,10,22,36,52,225,37,241,23,24,25,26,38,39,40,41,42,53,54,55,56,57,58,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,99,100,101,102,103,104,105,106,115,116,117,118,119,120,121,122,130,131,132,133,134,135,136,137,138,146,147,148,149,150,151,152,153,154,162,163,164,165,166,167,168,169,170,178,179,180,181,182,183,184,185,186,194,195,196,197,198,199,200,201,202,210,211,212,213,214,215,216,217,218,226,227,228,229,230,231,232,233,234,242,243,244,245,246,247,248,249,250,255,218,0,12,3,1,0,2,17,3,17,0,63,0,244,45,114,242,250,233,86,43,43,54,153,142,17,17,20,119,238,125,133,70,254,25,210,116,173,41,219,88,101,184,45,243,202,167,128,231,223,29,135,165,110,92,78,186,54,151,230,150,81,43,40,45,249,116,175,26,241,119,137,47,181,40,110,100,18,236,137,50,160,147,212,251,80,6,244,254,56,180,18,174,147,225,189,54,217,1,237,26,5,11,238,113,93,111,134,52,137,22,195,203,189,62,116,123,139,199,188,12,224,243,131,244,53,225,62,2,186,134,127,16,195,231,57,89,85,88,46,63,143,53,232,87,126,48,212,244,155,89,82,57,21,252,178,84,35,117,62,194,128,59,189,87,71,176,42,75,70,136,7,125,216,197,121,238,185,117,99,167,220,136,81,227,17,242,164,22,4,243,92,222,173,226,95,16,234,54,187,158,237,45,201,228,162,117,30,220,215,50,45,46,53,9,135,155,60,146,99,185,61,79,181,0,117,23,115,171,217,67,37,179,7,96,165,14,7,110,198,178,155,198,218,157,130,125,154,34,152,92,96,50,231,21,210,105,154,98,174,143,184,70,207,33,82,188,26,198,185,240,243,76,50,161,68,157,72,35,173,0,58,31,19,106,250,133,194,194,109,226,44,195,6,100,207,25,246,60,86,197,174,155,169,233,250,132,114,201,34,220,171,21,37,212,14,9,237,88,86,150,242,90,76,171,44,46,8,61,186,87,113,166,223,36,177,121,109,149,35,144,9,160,14,179,70,157,101,136,51,34,250,30,42,214,176,176,221,104,114,66,202,191,188,59,71,203,89,150,23,8,136,170,163,32,213,237,86,104,173,45,109,154,89,124,180,103,193,61,179,239,64,28,148,150,209,105,133,109,138,6,218,51,156,123,209,92,143,142,124,111,10,120,136,195,102,86,88,226,137,81,157,122,22,201,39,249,209,64,29,255,0,142,245,139,223,33,133,180,13,180,39,223,98,0,28,87,139,234,250,164,141,167,52,56,232,56,53,234,62,55,75,153,161,116,135,11,30,0,36,245,63,74,243,123,237,2,234,230,25,2,176,24,3,175,122,0,195,240,181,218,218,120,134,210,103,144,34,171,140,147,210,189,47,82,154,17,173,22,225,163,147,4,115,94,93,111,162,92,157,68,91,206,166,48,191,51,55,183,181,118,102,127,50,221,72,224,194,0,25,60,226,128,54,110,237,99,184,155,101,188,113,184,39,140,247,169,162,210,197,132,45,44,161,76,164,112,58,0,42,150,155,169,196,160,74,121,96,106,182,163,168,29,75,81,183,180,121,246,67,44,128,72,192,253,213,207,52,1,217,90,55,149,105,8,40,0,108,156,227,175,53,79,196,33,52,203,133,157,79,201,32,202,140,84,218,149,252,86,86,118,118,160,135,84,82,51,158,163,61,105,215,207,101,119,162,38,161,113,56,17,218,70,99,117,206,73,201,249,112,59,231,165,0,98,217,77,109,125,1,37,134,107,74,219,72,142,88,37,154,214,98,38,136,22,40,220,134,30,149,203,91,105,151,74,235,53,161,96,28,231,203,62,245,218,232,107,36,108,201,58,16,72,198,72,245,160,11,26,12,205,60,241,247,199,173,108,124,65,211,69,255,0,129,238,178,79,238,64,147,229,235,197,84,209,108,205,164,220,129,203,117,246,237,93,101,220,43,113,163,205,11,128,202,233,130,15,113,64,31,39,75,99,11,72,74,202,64,247,162,186,15,20,232,241,105,222,33,185,183,133,128,140,28,129,233,69,0,122,95,138,238,143,144,62,110,184,6,178,99,66,232,234,6,121,167,107,50,197,61,191,223,4,227,142,104,178,154,35,98,25,165,64,216,193,5,135,90,0,196,212,162,17,101,215,1,133,115,199,81,141,46,195,57,10,92,96,143,90,223,214,110,34,242,219,18,41,247,6,188,226,246,115,45,209,43,157,170,112,188,80,7,113,103,3,202,100,104,207,108,132,173,219,29,50,214,27,105,39,186,27,164,110,48,188,227,233,92,198,159,124,101,179,136,198,64,32,0,192,154,183,56,186,97,190,59,144,140,71,56,122,0,93,85,238,39,185,11,28,164,132,93,171,147,216,84,86,47,60,178,39,157,38,229,70,249,80,158,9,255,0,26,171,30,153,44,204,89,174,55,22,63,49,223,86,161,210,35,192,62,105,207,221,4,200,56,160,14,190,203,86,183,183,136,44,142,170,64,206,115,206,61,235,102,13,90,218,238,226,54,182,253,226,5,4,144,8,207,210,184,113,99,12,106,90,86,13,140,161,203,130,84,142,159,133,116,158,29,141,35,216,230,72,194,245,193,97,64,29,174,158,140,88,70,87,10,27,228,246,174,156,103,236,140,184,249,182,243,92,238,156,209,44,159,235,211,110,114,50,227,138,208,189,213,237,172,108,230,157,230,140,34,70,73,249,135,56,160,15,159,124,89,43,75,226,107,230,114,114,36,35,30,152,162,179,245,59,230,191,212,167,186,103,12,100,114,114,7,90,40,3,63,79,75,171,231,153,82,73,79,149,17,144,170,158,78,62,181,99,236,58,163,45,184,183,243,100,105,96,243,207,206,0,32,144,56,201,247,3,220,214,66,72,241,146,99,118,66,70,14,214,35,35,210,180,116,141,67,83,182,185,102,176,86,154,65,22,220,16,88,42,238,7,166,122,100,14,58,30,152,57,170,16,71,22,179,44,47,50,65,116,99,65,146,222,89,246,252,250,138,133,39,212,157,21,227,91,134,83,156,50,161,32,227,175,110,213,180,183,126,37,144,21,75,2,160,57,151,34,50,6,65,243,24,228,158,228,103,31,128,199,74,18,125,115,76,211,113,37,128,49,180,96,103,107,102,63,45,195,2,224,30,217,62,220,243,156,80,6,91,255,0,108,196,197,94,27,160,203,247,128,140,146,191,92,116,160,182,176,35,105,60,187,147,26,157,165,213,9,92,242,122,254,7,242,173,89,175,60,77,190,37,146,213,144,187,40,95,147,0,179,178,176,207,61,73,11,244,206,56,164,155,85,215,204,133,38,178,82,236,173,157,209,31,152,0,119,103,156,21,1,186,30,0,199,20,1,142,46,53,54,77,224,92,20,219,187,112,67,140,122,231,210,157,43,106,176,177,89,22,224,50,162,187,13,167,229,7,144,79,167,227,90,208,95,248,138,222,27,88,97,180,242,150,211,230,140,121,7,230,59,74,243,234,113,158,61,122,226,144,223,235,122,72,23,13,167,249,18,29,143,19,149,36,70,177,171,39,66,78,120,111,226,207,175,112,104,3,32,29,81,155,110,203,144,115,131,185,8,3,235,158,148,159,241,51,198,76,119,67,208,20,96,79,78,158,189,69,116,6,255,0,196,43,4,119,49,37,181,210,176,82,190,94,233,89,3,114,185,4,240,6,14,61,14,77,84,135,83,241,30,249,145,109,94,66,31,108,136,98,39,7,37,176,121,233,243,156,246,193,25,226,128,49,238,14,161,106,229,46,86,226,22,7,24,144,21,231,175,245,21,9,184,152,240,101,115,245,106,218,212,109,245,237,70,40,69,198,158,120,37,215,203,140,238,193,227,212,224,100,116,227,158,113,205,103,54,141,168,164,111,35,90,72,169,28,102,71,44,49,128,58,245,235,140,142,153,235,64,20,204,175,253,227,69,50,138,0,43,71,73,251,127,155,49,176,198,245,64,239,184,46,0,86,4,54,91,129,131,206,125,171,58,175,105,144,94,220,188,209,217,74,35,44,129,36,203,237,12,25,130,133,247,201,32,83,3,97,32,241,70,252,37,161,11,16,48,132,217,24,69,28,49,80,58,99,156,254,126,244,142,222,33,183,130,19,33,128,199,47,238,129,62,91,100,72,199,229,111,246,88,140,250,112,13,61,244,223,19,171,249,82,93,229,129,193,79,60,59,41,4,156,96,103,13,146,220,117,60,246,6,155,253,149,175,50,53,187,93,198,99,65,130,190,114,130,161,112,70,79,96,9,67,215,3,35,173,32,29,125,15,136,217,15,155,182,120,224,34,102,146,34,132,43,0,27,156,119,224,28,119,219,197,54,8,252,71,116,109,239,160,183,45,144,94,39,68,64,9,32,12,227,185,192,29,123,10,95,176,234,210,203,117,107,113,170,68,161,225,89,231,87,39,7,32,128,8,43,193,27,125,176,41,215,9,226,75,103,183,182,184,189,217,185,115,24,50,174,17,81,119,110,60,112,54,242,15,113,249,86,117,28,210,188,45,243,42,54,234,57,79,137,145,214,72,209,3,68,196,163,39,149,242,51,227,56,57,224,190,65,199,241,100,82,92,90,235,207,109,53,175,217,214,120,221,192,50,13,184,109,185,59,0,60,231,44,125,248,227,165,75,246,63,19,91,89,180,70,100,72,203,42,6,46,55,13,184,0,14,51,200,35,158,184,3,145,138,87,177,241,44,178,188,19,234,91,110,160,42,98,132,204,55,51,28,129,130,58,18,161,136,207,97,218,185,125,188,247,230,143,226,105,200,187,50,157,141,190,191,14,161,29,172,114,45,172,240,68,29,124,214,65,181,14,80,125,126,241,24,235,214,161,251,78,183,163,237,186,184,129,68,82,179,99,204,85,96,219,151,4,3,207,202,66,143,99,182,173,46,155,226,11,128,111,5,204,43,41,13,27,18,234,140,87,119,36,156,99,5,177,131,215,167,106,203,107,109,99,81,142,205,29,100,153,100,66,109,195,50,242,170,57,193,244,30,134,186,169,205,77,110,155,91,216,206,74,195,91,93,212,94,49,25,157,118,130,14,4,106,58,116,237,208,103,2,146,93,111,80,154,221,160,150,101,104,217,4,100,24,215,238,129,128,58,118,172,254,135,7,181,21,169,34,26,40,52,82,0,169,237,238,238,45,4,162,222,86,143,205,77,142,80,224,149,200,56,207,212,10,215,211,124,29,173,106,182,113,221,218,195,15,145,39,221,103,153,84,145,156,116,235,212,87,71,31,195,219,9,24,227,81,184,217,206,27,106,242,58,41,252,112,199,233,138,46,7,16,53,27,225,210,242,224,125,37,62,152,166,11,203,160,197,133,204,192,158,167,204,60,244,255,0,1,249,87,161,75,240,223,77,17,66,203,169,93,43,77,15,158,160,4,115,183,36,99,28,115,145,85,199,195,203,28,127,200,67,80,255,0,192,100,255,0,226,168,184,28,57,189,186,98,204,215,51,22,101,216,196,200,114,87,57,193,246,205,75,22,165,123,12,162,84,185,151,204,84,100,87,44,73,80,195,7,30,149,217,127,194,190,177,3,63,111,212,112,57,63,232,201,255,0,197,84,23,222,7,180,179,251,63,151,127,52,134,101,102,34,85,17,236,10,1,231,25,245,164,236,213,152,206,80,234,87,196,161,55,183,39,97,202,230,86,224,251,115,77,125,66,245,246,238,188,184,59,78,70,101,110,15,62,254,231,243,53,217,219,248,6,198,226,198,222,232,106,55,127,190,64,251,99,137,27,111,226,72,205,56,252,62,177,11,184,223,106,95,65,110,159,252,85,46,88,246,11,179,138,109,78,253,139,19,125,114,75,125,236,202,220,244,30,190,195,242,171,49,79,168,167,217,93,45,110,24,68,25,144,225,206,230,110,249,244,233,199,79,206,186,223,248,87,54,238,170,45,239,174,12,239,40,141,18,225,82,53,57,231,59,129,56,29,106,204,126,7,150,212,52,115,235,55,241,77,11,108,242,237,92,72,160,21,12,8,36,140,112,122,99,32,211,73,45,131,83,207,26,202,243,134,54,151,31,48,220,15,148,121,7,191,74,73,44,238,162,93,242,91,76,171,140,238,40,113,249,215,160,255,0,194,23,10,160,63,219,26,216,0,109,0,70,188,15,79,189,210,164,95,1,91,203,4,138,218,222,166,169,208,164,138,184,111,195,61,41,220,71,153,154,42,246,181,167,141,39,89,186,176,89,76,171,3,237,14,87,5,184,7,167,227,69,0,45,182,185,170,218,64,144,91,106,23,17,68,131,10,136,248,3,252,230,163,184,213,47,238,161,16,220,94,77,36,106,65,10,205,192,32,96,126,67,138,40,160,6,79,168,94,93,34,36,247,83,72,177,140,32,103,39,21,6,230,254,243,126,102,138,40,0,220,223,222,111,204,211,150,105,23,149,145,129,250,154,40,160,4,243,31,251,237,255,0,125,26,77,239,253,246,255,0,190,141,20,80,2,249,142,57,222,223,153,160,200,231,146,237,159,173,20,80,1,230,63,247,219,254,250,52,155,223,251,237,255,0,125,26,40,160,4,103,102,108,177,44,79,82,78,73,162,138,40,3,255,217]
```

how to convert this type of data to image and set it to imageview?
can anyone help me?
thanks in advance.

Comment: what is that array containing is it bitmap?

Comment: it is varbinary array and i want to convert it to image

Comment: Is that a json array @gaurang?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should give you a good help:

```
String myString = "[255,216,255....]";
try {
    JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(myString);
    byte[] myArray = new byte[myString.length()];
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {
        myArray[i] = (byte) arr.getInt(i);
    }
    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(myArray, 0, myArray.length);
    ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myImageView);
    image.setImageBitmap(bmp);
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**Result:**

[image]

**Explaining the steps:**

- Start by converting that string to a JsonArray
- Convert all items in it to bytes and add them to an byte[]
- Convert the byte array to a bitmap
- Set that bitmap on your image

Answer (score 0):

Convert **String Array to byte Array**. Like,

Assume *temp* is your String Array.

```
byte[] byteArray = new byte[temp.length];
int index = 0;
  for (String item: temp) {
     byteArray[index] = Byte.parseByte(item);
   index++;
  }
```

then Convert **Byte Array to Image**. like,

```
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

image.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

Hope this will helps you.

Comment: @Pedro any problem on first snippet?

Comment: Yes. It will convert a complete string to it's byte array. The string given by the OP is an array of bytes. So it should not be converted to byte array like you did. That string should be iterated and each integer inside it should be converted to byte.

Comment: no errors  it is just surrounding everything between try and catch block and no image is diplayed